How to fix the PathVariable is not working and throw 500 Error Server?
I'm coding Java Spring and I don't understand why when I use PathVariable in function retrieveTodoForUser to access this function, an Internal Server Error 500 occurs.
enter image description here
enter image description here
Please help me, I sincerely thank you

Please do not put screenshot of your code, use the inline formating. Also do you have any debug logs ?

@Maxime , Thank you, I am sorry, This is the first time I use Stackoverflow to post a question, I fixed it, I wrote the solution in the answer section.

I fixed, I don't know, but this is my first time using gradle, before I used maven and didn't encounter this problem, I used @PathVariable("username") instead of `@PathVariable.
